# Differing behavior of Eigenvalues and Eigensystem

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

With the update to v12.0, I seem to be getting different behavior of eigenvalues returned by `Eigenvalues` and `Eigensystem` (oddly, this managed to break some older code of mine that I revisited). Here's a MWE:

```
A={{1,1,1},{1,0,0},{0,1,0}};
Eigenvalues[A]===Eigensystem[A][[1]]
(*False*)
Eigenvalues[A]==Eigensystem[A][[1]]
(*Giant equation*)
Eigenvalues[A]==Eigensystem[A][[1]]//Simplify
(*Same giant equation*)
Eigenvalues[A]==Eigensystem[A][[1]]//FullSimplify
(*True*)
Eigenvalues[A]==Eigensystem[A][[1]]//Reduce
(*True*)
```

I could swear that all of these returned `(*True*)` in v11, but I don't have an install to verify this.
In comparison,

```
Sort[Diagonal[JordanDecomposition[A][[2]]]] == Sort[Eigenvalues[A]]
(*True*)
Sort[Diagonal[JordanDecomposition[A][[2]]]] == Eigenvalues[A]
(*False*)
```

despite `Eigenvalues` purportedly returning a sorted list of eigenvalues (appears to be a simple matter of reordering the complex conjugate roots).

### Questions

1. Is this now expected behavior?
2. What changed? I assume that this has to do with the new front end for irrational numbers, which is admittedly much prettier than `Root` objects.
3. Observing that `Eigensystem[#][[1]]&` returns different `Root` objects than `Eigenvalues` and `Diagonal[JordanDecomposition[#][[1]]]&`, is Mathematica really using a different backend algorithm? If so, why? Should I be concerned about any numerical stability impacts?

#### Edit

Including a screenshot with a fresh kernel to further document this difference.
[image: Eigenvalues vs Eigensystem]

#### Edit 2

Following a comment from @bills, slight differences persist using numerical arithmetic as well. This introduces a whole slew of other test cases that produce differing behavior, as shown below.
[image: Eigenvalues using numerics]

Comment: Yes, that seems to be a version 12 change. I have no idea why `Eigensystem[]` would return a weird format, even if they are algebraically equivalent to the results of `Eigenvalues[]`.

Comment: Don't know about others, but my V12.0.0.0 on Linux x86 gives `True` for all in the first block.

Comment: @Max1 Very strange! I am in fact on v12.1.0.0---perhaps this is the difference? Window 10, x86-64 for reference

Comment: If you change one of the integer 1 to 1.0, then you get False,True,True,True,True.

Comment: @bills Interesting! It looks like `Eigenvalues[N[A]]` lists the real eigenvalue as `1.83929 + 0. I`. Even better, `Eigensystem[A][[1, 1]] - Eigenvalues[N[A]][[1]]` returns `0. + 2.33731*10^-17 I`

Comment: @erfink what are the specs of your system?

Comment: @CATrevillian v12.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 14, 2020). Machine type PC Windows 10 Home 64-bit, x86-64 processor (Intel Core i7-6700K, Skylake 14nm).

Comment: I ran your example in 11.2.0.0. The first five indeed all returned "True", but I didn't test enough examples to know if that is generally the case. I don't blindly trust Mathematica to test equality for machine-precision numbers, because it returns true if the difference is small . Another subtlety is that for machine precision numbers, x >y and x - y >0 do NOT always return the same result. The former one considers x>y false for x close enough to y to be considered equal to x, even if the latter returns true.  I haven't investigated arbitrary-precision, which has its own pathologies.